# Use jquery to find elements that contain a specific ID and highlight them

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm a jquery/javascript noob so not really sure how to go about this. I want to modify a website that's already been served to me in my browser.

There are some boxes on the left hand side and then there are arrows going from these boxes to other boxes on the right hand side. What I am attempting to do is use a click event listener to click on a box on the left, have it highlighted, and also highlight the arrow that is associated with this box.

Here's what I have so far and it works to highlight the left hand side box. What I want to also do is highlight any arrows that contain this ID as there can be multiple arrows originating from a box.

```
javascript: document.designMode = "on"; document.designMode = "on"; 

$("div[example]").on('click', function(e) { 
    var t = $(this).attr('id'); 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    console.log(t);

});
```

I can print the correct element ID (e.g. ID_of_lefthandbox) out when I click on the box. So using this ID I would like to then find the arrow(s) on the webpage that contains this ID. Here is what the path looks like:

```
<path to-id="12345" approved="true" id="43210" from-id="ID_of_lefthandbox" stroke-width="2" fill="" d="M5,193 53,261" stroke="DarkGreen" stroke-linecap="round" marker-end="url(#markGreenArrow)"></path>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the attribute `from-id` contains the `id` of the lefthandbox you are looking for, the following works:

```
 $("div[example]").on('click', function(e) { 
    var t = $(this).attr('id'); 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    $("path[from-id='" + t + "']").css("background-color", "red");
    console.log(t);
 });
```

Comment: Yes this does seem to be on the right track. I can see this background color attribute added to the path when I inspect it but I think it is either hidden or overridden by the existing css. Is there a way to do the same as I did with event "preventdefault" on this path?

Comment: @Kevys You can try the following: replace the line $("path[from-id='" + t etc with the lines  let arrow = $("path[from-id='" + t + "']"); arrow[0].style.setProperty('background-color', 'red', 'important'); This should work if the existing css doesn't use !important, too.

Comment: Thank you @matthias_h for the suggestion. While it did not work it did give me the idea - why not just change the stroke color? So I did with this line

$("path[from-id='" + t + "']").css({"stroke":"red", "stroke-width":"10"});

Thanks again!

Comment: @Kevys Glad that I was able to help :)